# Docker mulitstage build jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm using a multistage build in docker and I can create it perfectly fine on local. I'm using Jenkins to build the images in my CI process. All my single stage builds work, so it must have something to do with the mulit stage. When Jenkins starts building the image I get the following:

```
Step 1/11 : FROM node:8.1.4-alpine as builder
Error parsing reference: "node:8.1.4-alpine as builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as ‘builder’
FROM node:8.1.4-alpine as builder

COPY package.json ./

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod


### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I'm using the the following jenkins version: `jenkins/jenkins:2.95``

Could someone pls hint me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Are docker versions different? You might be using a older docker version which doesn't support multi stage build. I think it came in 17.05 or 17.06 if I remember it correctly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not the 100% solution to the problem, but I stopped using multistage builds. Basically just using the stage 2 and building the production version manually beforehand.

```
### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```